# Posting action on timeline with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php
require "src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'=>'xxxxxxxxx',
'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'cookie'=>true
));

if(!$facebook->getUser())
{
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,publish_actions'));
echo "<script> top.location=\"".$url."\"; </script>";
exit(0);
}

$params = array('article'=>'http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/script/','access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken());

$out = $facebook->api('/me/namespace:read','post',$params);

print_r($out);

exit(0);

?>
```

But i got some questions, where should i put these meta tags? i only found javascript examples and i got another question how to use a dynamic url like:

http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/script/?article_id=xxxx

if i try to put some parameter in this url it returns error like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/script/?article_id=xxxx has og:type of 'website'. The property 'article' requires an object of og:type 'namespace:article'. thrown in xxxxxxx on line 1106
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Within the **<head>** section of http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/script/?article_id=xxxx you should add something like this:

```
<head>
    <title>My article</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My article" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="namespace:article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/script/?article_id=xxxx" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxx" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="My wonderful article" />
</head>
```

From the namespace in the error message I'm guessing that you defined your own **article** object and didn't use the [builtin article object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#article).

Comment: He isn't trying to do it via JavaScript SDK, which this would work fine for. PHP SDK doesn't see this information at all.

Comment: I disagree. The error message originates from Facebook's scraper. The scraper doesn't care which SDK you choose.

Comment: You are right, I reread the documents and saw that it is actually required.